# How to enable/install the "compatibility layer" in Maven Tycho Surefire so that Platform.getPlugin() works

Tags: eclipse-plugin, tycho, e4, tycho-surefire-plugin

I [have a test failure](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/65282/) due to an `IllegalStateException` from `Platform.getPlugin("...")` which calls `@Deprecated` `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getPluginRegistry()` which "only works if the compatibility layer is installed and must not be used otherwise."

This test works in-workspace during development, but fails (reproducible) when ran by Maven Tycho Surefire.  I gathered that this has something to do with `org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility`, so have attempted to do this in the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        ...     
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <bundleStartLevel>
            <bundle>
                <id>org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility</id>
                <level>4</level>
                <autoStart>true</autoStart>
            </bundle>
        </bundleStartLevel>
    </configuration>
```

Unfortunately even with this (above) it still does not work - what am I doing wrong?

As an alternative Answer to fix this, I guess I could try to adapt that line in the test to use another API than this deprecated `Platform.getPlugin()` - but how do you obtain an org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin given an ID without using any deprecated APIs requiring this compatibility layer which is causing me issues here?

Answer (score 1):

Actually simply `Platform.getBundle()` instead of `Platform.getPlugin()` did the trick.

Also, just in case anyone else ever hits this, the extra dependency configuration does work - it just lead to ANOTHER unrelated IllegalStateException in my specific test case, which caused me confusion.

Comment: Glad you solved it, but note the difference between getPlugin() and getBundle(). The first returns the Plugin (i.e. the bundle activator) while the latter the bundle descriptor.